# How to add adapter for childview of expandableRecycler view?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

In the child view, I want suitable single items to be displayed, but it is showing all the required items in all the occurring child view's! how to solve this? [see this pic for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du0Z5.png)

and this my code for setting Titles(Parent Item) based on keys and also setting descriptions(Child items) based on keys received

```
Map<String, String> getdes(int keyId,int valId){
        String[] key = getResources().getStringArray(keyId);
        String[] des = getResources().getStringArray(valId);

        Map<String, String> dict = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for (int i=0, l=des.length; i<l; i++){
            dict.put(key[i],des[i]);
        }
        return dict;
    }
//this for titles
    Map<String, String> getDict(int keyId, int valId) {
        String[] keys = getResources().getStringArray(keyId);
        String[] vals = getResources().getStringArray(valId);

        Map<String, String> dict = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
            dict.put(keys[i], vals[i]);
        }
        return dict;
    }

    private void dataOk(String res) {
        FaultTitle title;
        FaultDesc d1; /*= new FaultDesc("ghj");*/
        Map<String, String> dtcVals = getDict(R.array.dtc_keys, R.array.dtc_values);
        Map<String , String> dtcdes = getdes(R.array.dtc_keys,R.array.dtc_descrip);
        if (res != null) {
            for (String dtcCode : res.split("\n")) {
                d1 = new FaultDesc(dtcCode, dtcdes.get(dtcCode));
                des.add(d1);
                Log.d("Trouble codes", dtcCode + " : " + dtcVals.get(dtcCode)+ ": "+ numberFaults);
                title = new FaultTitle(dtcCode,dtcVals.get(dtcCode), des);
                titles.add(title);
                Log.d("TEST", titles.get(numberFaults).getFaultCode() + " -- "+ titles.get(numberFaults).getFaultTitle());
                numberFaults++;
            }

            fault_counter.setText(numberFaults+"");

            mAdapter = new FaultAdapter(getContext(),titles);

            recyclerViewFaults.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
           //TODO NO FAULTS
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        remoteDevice = prefs.getString(ConfigActivity.BLUETOOTH_LIST_KEY, null);
        if (remoteDevice == null || "".equals(remoteDevice)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No Bluetooth device has been selected.");
            mHandler.obtainMessage(NO_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SELECTED).sendToTarget();
        } else {
            gtct = new GetTroubleCodesTask();
            gtct.execute(remoteDevice);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_faults, container, false);

        recyclerViewFaults = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewFaults);
        fault_counter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fault_counter);

        mAdapter = new FaultAdapter(view.getContext(),titles);

        recyclerViewFaults.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerViewFaults.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));

        return view;
    }
```

This is Adapter class :

```
public class FaultAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<FaultTitleViewHolder,FaultDescViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflator;
    private List<FaultTitle> mTitleList;
    private List<FaultDesc> mChildList;

    public FaultAdapter(Context context, @NonNull List<FaultTitle> parentItemList) {
        super(parentItemList);
        mTitleList = parentItemList;
        mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public FaultTitleViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parentViewGroup) {
        View movieCategoryView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.view_fault_title, parentViewGroup, false);
        return new FaultTitleViewHolder(movieCategoryView);
    }

    @Override
    public FaultDescViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup childViewGroup) {
        View moviesView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.view_fault_desc, childViewGroup, false);
        return new FaultDescViewHolder(moviesView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindParentViewHolder(FaultTitleViewHolder faultTitleViewHolder, int position, @NonNull ParentListItem parentListItem) {
        FaultTitle faultTitle = (FaultTitle) parentListItem;
        faultTitleViewHolder.bind(faultTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(FaultDescViewHolder faultDescViewHolder, int position, @NonNull Object childListItem) {
        FaultDesc faultDesc = (FaultDesc) childListItem;
        faultDescViewHolder.bind(faultDesc);
    }
}
```

This is getter class of Titles(Parent Items) and and Description(Child Items)

```
public class FaultTitle implements ParentListItem{

    private String mFaultCode, mFaultTitle;
    private List<FaultDesc> mFaultDesc;

    public FaultTitle(String mFaultCode, String mFaultTitle, List<FaultDesc> mFaultDesc) {
        this.mFaultCode = mFaultCode;
        this.mFaultTitle = mFaultTitle;
        this.mFaultDesc = mFaultDesc;
    }

    public String getFaultCode() {
        return mFaultCode;
    }

    public String getFaultTitle() {
        return mFaultTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public List<FaultDesc> getChildItemList() {
        return mFaultDesc;
    }

    public List<FaultDesc> getmFaultDesc() {
        return mFaultDesc;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInitiallyExpanded() {
        return false;
    }
}

public class FaultDesc {

    private String faultDesc, mFaultCode;

    public FaultDesc(String dtccode, String faultDesc) {
        this.faultDesc = faultDesc;
        this.mFaultCode = dtccode;
    }

    public FaultDesc(String faultDesc) {
        this.faultDesc = faultDesc;
    }



    public String getFaultDesc() {
        return faultDesc;
    }

    public String getmFaultCode() {
        return mFaultCode;
    }
}
```

this my arrays I'm using:

```
<string-array name="dtc_descrip">
        <item>Wiring, regulator control solenoid. </item>
        <item>Wiring, regulator control solenoid. </item>
        <item>Wiring short to earth, regulator control solenoid. </item>
        <item>Wiring open circuit/short to positive, regulator control solenoid. </item>
        <item>Wiring open circuit, fuel shut -off valve. </item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="dtc_keys">
            <item>P0001</item>
            <item>P0002</item>
            <item>P0003</item>
            <item>P0004</item>
            <item>P0005</item>
</string-array>

 <string-array name="dtc_values">
            <item>Fuel Volume Regulator Control Circuit/Open</item>
            <item>Fuel Volume Regulator Control Circuit Range/Performance</item>
            <item>Fuel Volume Regulator Control Circuit Low</item>
            <item>Fuel Volume Regulator Control Circuit High</item>
            <item>Fuel Shutoff Valve A Control Circuit/Open</item>
</string-array>
```